# qPython bytes type exception in sync query

Tags: python, kdb, qpython

I'm trying to query KDB with the following select statement: `{select from order where OrderID = x}`. When passing in the parameter it keeps throwing b'lenghth exceptions. I've tried `numpy.string_`, `numpy.bytes_` and regular `bytes` using the `.encode()` method (latin-1 and utf-8).

When I query one record to investigate the type of the OrderID column, it tells me the column type is `bytes`.

What am I doing wrong? Not sure what the dash in the [docs](http://qpython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/type-conversion.html) is supposed to mean. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like the type of `OrderID` on the kdb side is a character list. In which case you need to use `like` to do the comparison in your query:

```
{select from order where OrderID like x}
```

And then you should be able to use a regular Python string for the parameter, .e.g.

```
q.sync("{select from order where OrderID like x}", "my_order_id")
```

As long as you don't use any wildcard characters in parameter `x` then this will only match on the exact string. i.e.

```
 q)"one" like "one"
1b
q)"ones" like "one"
0b
q)"ones" like "one*"
1b
```

Comment: Saviour!! Worked like a charm! Thank you so much (have been struggling with it all day).